# Hide categories in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hide

I used this code to hidding product categories in woocommerce.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'filter_get_terms', 10, 3 );
function filter_get_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $new_terms = [];

    // if a product category and on the shop page
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $term-> slug, [ 'seinakellad', 'nastennye-chasy', 'wall-clock', 'juuksekammid', 'grebni-dlja-volos', 'hair-combs' ] ) ) {
                $new_terms[] = $term;
            }
        }

        $terms = $new_terms;
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

After updating to PHP 8.2 i got this error:
**
Warning**: Attempt to read property "slug" on int in **/data01/virt81820/domeenid/www.enjoythewoodestonia.ee/test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(505) : eval()'d code** on line **8**

So...whats a problem with that "slug" and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to hide products from these categories?

Comment: No, i want to hide categories. In my example "wall-clock" and "hair-combs" are categories. When they are empty, woocommerce does not hide them from the shop page for example. So i found that CSS hides categories manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 
'woo_hide_car_category_widget' );
function woo_hide_car_category_widget( $list_args ) {
  $list_args['exclude'] = array( 'car' );
  return $list_args;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for my shop

Comment: Sorry, may be my question wasnt correct. How can i hide any category i want, not only empty?

Comment: @MrLoco I updated the code, please replace the word "car" to the category you want to hide.

Comment: Hi. your new code hides all categories from widget - "No product categories exist.". 
So it is not working correctly